# I am unable to upload variant image to shopify using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest, shopify, shopify-api

I have been trying since days but I can not. I want to upload products with multiple options/variants and its images, product images its variant & options are uploaded but variant images are not being assigned. What I have tried since. Event it does not show the error, products are uploading but not variant images

1# Using Shopify SDK

```
$shopify = new ShopifySDK($config);
 $products = $shopify->Product->post($product_array);
 $productVariants = $shopify->ProductVariant->post($id, $variant_array);
 $image = $shopify->Image->post($v_id, $images_array)
```

2# Using

```
Signifly\Shopify\Shopify;
```

```
 $product = $shopify->createProduct($array);            // inserting whole product, variant, options and images at a time
```

and uploading separately

```
$shopify->createProduct($product_array);
$shopify->createVariant($id, $variant_array);
$shopify->createProductImage($id, $images_array);
```

#3 Using Rest api

```
 $client = new Rest('mystore-6842.myshopify.com', 'shpat_*********************');
        $response = $client->get('products');
            $products_array = array(
                "product" => array( 
                    "title"        => 'title of product',
                    "body_html"    => 'description',
                    "vendor"       => "vendor of product",
                    "published"    => true ,
                    "variants"     => array(
                        array(
                            "sku"     => 'sku of product',
                            "price"   => 'product price',
                            "taxable" => false,
                            "inventory_quantity"=> 'available quantity',
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
            
            $shop = Shopify::shop();
         
            $products=$shop->api()->rest('POST','admin/api/2023-01/products.json',$products_array);
```

in the rest api package is unable to locate my shop.

Comment: Question: At what part of your code does the error occur, and what is the exact error you are getting? Could you maybe update your question with this info please?

Comment: @Techno it does not show any error, it uploads each and every information except variant images